cor() function in R returns NA when given two integers or continuous values
Using R version 4.4.0, I was using the cor() function and originally inputting two continuous values to obtain a default calculated correlation. NA is returned instead of a numeric. I'm able to reproduce this using the following:
cor(12, 16); cor(12.1242, 16.1235)
[1] NA
[1] NA

As seen, there exists no missing values in these examples and the output is mysterious to me. I was originally following someone else's code and could not obtain the same numerical output they could. The original code uses cor() on continuous value as in the second example.
Any insights?

The correlation of two numbers doesn't exist, hence why you are getting NA. You are going to need more data, the coefficient is defined when you have at least two observations.
If you want to calculate the correlation of two vectors, you can achieve it as follows:
> cor(c(12.1242, 2, 3), c(16.1235, 6, 0))
[1] 0.8930372

If you have a dataframe, for example trees, you can calculate the correlation of two variables as follows:
> cor(trees['Girth'], trees['Height'])
         Height
Girth 0.5192801

With that said, you can pass the function the entire dataframe, and it will compute all of the correlations
> cor(trees)
           Girth    Height    Volume
Girth  1.0000000 0.5192801 0.9671194
Height 0.5192801 1.0000000 0.5982497
Volume 0.9671194 0.5982497 1.0000000


Thank you, though now I'm stumped as to how the author of the code could have successfully run a correlation on two numbers. Oh well

@vficarrotta do you have a link to the example? What was the result you were expecting?
